# How can i determine first row of html table using angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

I can think of a few hacky ways, but for example below in my doSomething method, how can i determine the rowIndex?

```
        <tr ng-repeat="a in mydata">
            <td><b>{{doSomething(mydata.name)}}</b></td>
            <td>{{age}}</td>
            <td>hello</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS automatically includes the magic `$index` in an ng-repeat. So you can get the row number like so:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="a in mydata">
  <td><b>{{doSomething($index)}}</b></td>
  <td>{{a.name}}</td>
  <td>{{a.age}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have been using angular for 1 day and i am LOVING IT!  Thanks for the quick easy answer.

Answer (score 7):

[ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) provides properties $first, $index, $middle, and $last.  Since in the title question you asked about the first row, you could pass $first as a boolean:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in mydata">
    <td><b>{{doSomething($first)}}</b></td>
    <td>{{a.age}}</td>
    <td>hello</td>
</tr>
```